# Unable to setState to React component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the state of my PlayerKey component here however the state won't update on a onClick action:

```
class PlayerKey extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeKeys:[]
        }
    }

    activateKey = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            activeKeys:["2","3"]
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="key" data-row-number={this.props.rowKey} data-key-number={this.props.dataKeyNumber} onClick={this.activateKey}></div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried console logging this.state in activateKey and it gives me the state of the component no problem (the blank array) so not sure why I can't update it?

Comment: Could you post the whole component?

Comment: why isn't `activateKey` defined inside of `PlayerKey`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my behalf, i've updated the code with the render function and the activateKey inside of PlayerKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` method in react is asynchronous and doesn't reflect the updated state value immediately.

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

So accessing the recently set state value *might* return the older value. To see whether the state has really been set or not, You can actually pass a function as callback in `setState` and see the updated state value. [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

As in your case, you can pass a function as callback as follows.

```
activateKey = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        activeKeys:["2","3"]
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.activeKeys); // This is guaranteed to return the updated state. 
    });
}
```

See this fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aLsnL5p/)