# State not being set in time for new setState() to register changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

We're building a pretty complex React component (content editor). The following code gets called every time an `activity` component `componentDidMount()` method is called, which is usually several of them right after the other almost instantly.

```
addActivityToMap(activityObj){
  const { 
    activityMap
  } = this.state;
  const map = [ ...activityMap ];
  map.push(activityObj);
  console.log(activityMap);
  this.setState({
    activityMap: map
  });
}
```

The problem is that when called in rapid succession, the `state.activityMap` is unpopulated as each `activityObj` is being pushed to it, so when the `addActivityToMap` execution cycle is over the `state.activityMap` array only has the final `activityObj` at index `0`.

So the console log output for a processed dataset with two elements that need to be pushed to the `activityMap` will look like

```
>[]
>[]
```

I'm assuming this happens because the state fails to fully update before the next object is pushed. This is very annoying because I do not have control over the pace at which these objects are being generated (they are coming from an custom entities in an instance of DraftJS). What are my options here?

Comment: Is there no way to consolidate the multiple calls into a wrapper like `buildActivities` which is called once and returns the final activity map array to be called once with `setState`?

Comment: setState is asynchronous, which is why you are running into the problem where it appears that the new state does not have the new activityMap yet.  You could take advantage of react's lifecycle hooks `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentWillUpdate/ componentDidUpdate` to check the new state against the old.

Comment: I solved the problem by attaching the activityMap property directly to the component (`this`) and adding a forceUpdate() function at the end of addActivityToMap. Considering I have no control over how often this function is called and can't hook into the location where it is called from (automatically generated components) I think this is the quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: You may find reading this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42209286/4248342) helpful.

Comment: Using `forceUpdate` is discouraged. Quoting from the docs. Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render()

Comment: I know, but this is an edge case as I need the component to re render when this data changes but I am unable to synchronously update it with this.setState (at least not without way more work and abstraction than it's worth).

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, but you can pass a callback as second argument that will be executed once the state has been uptated. `setState(nextState, callback)`

Here for the use with the callback: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

And more info here for the second implementation of `setState`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous